# Best practice to lock data objects

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, task

I wrote an application which handles large text files. Internally a text file is stored as a DataObject which contains several data like the rows of the file, the file path and so on. I can modify these files (the data object respectively) with the application. Because some methods are time-consuming I run them in a Task to avoid blocking the UI. Now, with a non-blocking UI, i want to ensure that the user does not try to modify a file which is currently being processed in a Task so I want to lock the DataObject. For that, i thought that I could add a lock object to the DataObject class. I would then lock the DataObject this way:

```cs
public class DataObject {
    public object LockObject = new object();
    // ...

    public DataObject() { }
}

public void timeConsumingMethod(DataObject data) {
    Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(() => {
        lock(data.LockObject) {
            // do work
        }
    }));
}
```

Is this the way to go? Or is there a better way?

Comment: I like the proposed solution, I would just be careful if You try to read from the object - this might cause issue with writing/reading at same time (or if You forget to lock it while reading). I would add my own question asking if the lock should be done inside properties while `getting/setting` value?

Comment: Consider use the `Task.Run` instead of `StartNew`, which [is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)

Comment: @VMAtm: I have read the post. Good blog at all. I hadn't thought about it yet. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never *expose* `LockObject`, hide implementation details:

```
private object m_LockObject = new object();
```

Next issue: why `timeConsumingMethod` receives `DataObject` instead of being
implemented within `DataObject`:

```
public class DataObject {
  // locking object is a private implementation detail
  private object m_LockObject = new object();

  // TheMethod works with "this" DataObject instance, that's why
  // the method belongs to DataObject
  // let's return Task (e.g. to await it)
  // Think on method's name; 
  public Task TheMethodAsync() {
    // Task.Factory.StartNew is evil
    return Task.Run(() => {
      lock (m_LockObject) {
        // ...
      } 
    });
  }

  ...
}
```

Then just call the method

```
 public void timeConsumingMethod(DataObject data) {
   // When designing public methods do not forget about validation
   if (null == data)
     throw new ArgumentNullException("data");

   // Think on awaiting the Task returned:
   // "i run them in a Taks ... to avoid blocking the UI"
   // await data.TheMethodAsync();  
   data.TheMethodAsync();  

   ...
 }
```

Comment: I don't want to implement the method within DataObject because i have many of such methods and i want to avoid inflating DataObject. Regardless of this way i'm interested whether there is a good solution without implementing all the methods in DataObject.

Comment: Ok, as a compromis i could use extension methods. This would not inflate DataObject and i'm able to keep my code clean and clair.

Comment: @ooorndtski: if `DataObject` is too large, it seems to be `DataObject` design problem. Is it possible to extract some classes from `DataObject`?

Comment: @ooorndtski: *extension methods* are good practice when you *can't change* target object (usually standard library one, e.g. `string`). If you in fact can redesign `DataObject` implementing *extension methods* just brings unwanted complexity.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. After thinking about your post i decided to redesign my application. Methods that modify instances of DataObject were added to DataObject.

Comment: @ooorndtski: try to keep *Single Responsibility* principle (please, see *SOLID* - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)); `DataObject` should have the data as well as the methods (modification included) to manipulate it.